# Error messages are not displaying correctly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
    else
      object      = record.is_a?(Array) ? record.last : record
      raise ArgumentError, "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" unless object
      object_name = options[:as] || model_name_from_record_or_class(object).param_key
      apply_form_for_options!(record, object, options)
    end
```

Hi, relatively new to Rails and programming in general. I'm getting this error when I try to submit a form with errors in them. It works perfectly fine when all the fields are filled in correctly, but if a form is missing something, it does not display the error like it should in this picture:

[image]

Instead, I get this:

[image]

Here is the code for the form:

```
<%= form_for(@quote) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Save a new quote..." %>
    <%= f.text_field :author, placeholder: "Author:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :source, placeholder: "Source:" %>
    </div>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the code for the error messages:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
   The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
  </div>
  <ul>
<% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

And here is the code for the QuotesController:

```
 class QuotesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

 def create
  @quote = current_user.quotes.build(quote_params)
   if @quote.save
    flash[:success] = "Quote saved!"
    redirect_to root_url
   else
    render 'static_pages/home'
   end
 end

def edit
end

def destroy
end

private

 def quote_params
  params.require(:quote).permit(:content, :author, :source)
 end
end
```

How do I fix it so that it renders errors correctly like in the first picture?

*** It turns out the code is actually working but the only problem is that the homepage of my site runs two forms that calls on the shared/error_messages which is why I'm guessing they conflict. When I remove one of the forms, the other form works fine. Any ideas on how to run two forms on the same page? ***

Comment: This may not be the problem, but I'd recommend replacing `if object.errors.any?` with `if object.error.present?`. `any?` with no block just tests if any one of the items in `errors` is `false` or `nil`, but `present?` will test if there are any errors present.

Comment: Concur with neuronaut. The error seems to suggest that object is nil or empty. Adding a check will allow you to avoid the error.

Comment: Agree with @MarsAtomic, the error seems pretty clear that the `@quote` object you are passing to the `form_for` method in your view is either `nil` or `empty`. Where do you set this instance variable? I noticed you don't have a `#new`  action, although you could be rendering the form from somewhere else. Additionally, once you get past this issue, I noticed that your `else` block in the controller just redirects to the home page. What you want is to render the form again, this time passing in the invalid @quote object so the errors partial in your form will render the offending input.

Comment: Yes the error is saying the object is either nil or empty because I am trying to submit an empty form even though there is a validation present that requires the quote to have content. The only problem is that it isn't rendering the flash displaying the errors as I'm hoping for. And the new action is being rendered from the homepage.

Comment: your @quote is empty, you need to initialize it as '@quote = Quote.new' in your 'new action'

Comment: I've tried that but the error page is still popping up

Comment: have you tried by putting this `@quote = current_user.quotes.build` in static_pages comtroller's home action

Comment: Yes I've already added that @AmitSharma. But now the problem is not that it doesn't render correctly, but errors do not render correctly if there are two forms on the page that calls for the shared/error_messages